# How to check who's an admin of the room?

Tags: hipchat

I'm using HipChat and I'd like to know who's the admin of the current channel.

Which option or command can I use?

I've checked [Keyboard shortcuts and slash commands](https://confluence.atlassian.com/hipchat/keyboard-shortcuts-and-slash-commands-749385232.html) page, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways:

- On the HipChat clients, if you look at the 'users' list in the sidebar, the room admin will be displayed in bold letters.
- On the website, if you go to https://hipchat.com/rooms, there is a 'room admin' column that lists this info.